# A const string constructor that doesn't allocate any char memory?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, constants

I'm trying to optimize some code I've written to handle several layers of an application protocol. I made liberal use of the `std::string` class, and strove for simplicity rather than premature optimization. The application is too slow, and **valgrind** & **gprof** show I'm spending significant time copy-constructing strings as a buffer moves upward through my stack.

It seems to me that, after copying chars from the system buffer to my lowest application buffer, I should be able to avoid copying the data any more: after all, it is not mutated as it moves up the stack.

My protocol format is a "transmission", consisting of one or more newline-terminated **records**, each consisting of several tab-separated **fields**, and terminated with a special token.  E.g.

```
RECORD 1\tHAS\tTHESE\tFIELDS\nRECORD 2\tLOOKS\tLIKE\tTHIS\nEND-OF-TRANSMISSION\n
```

This would be assembled in a single `std::string` called input_buffer.

The processing of a transmission involves extracting a **record** from the buffer and passing it to the next layer; extracting a vector of **fields** from the record and passing it to the next layer; storing the fields into a map.  At each stage, data is being copied as new std::strings are allocated.

Is it possible to allocate a const string from an index into input_buffer, and a length ... without any copying being done?  For example, RECORD 2 begins at offset 26 and is 24 chars long:

```
const std:string record (substr(input_buffer, 26), 24 );
```

I'm not familiar with the innards of a string object, but its performance guarantees seem to imply that somewhere there's a simple char sequence, and almost undoubtedly a pointer to those chars' memory.  Could that pointer be initialized to memory belonging to another string?

(My compiler is g++ 4.7, but if this is something that requires 4.8, I'd appreciate knowing about that too.)

Comment: What's the lifetime of the `input_buffer`? And how long does the processed records and fields survive at each stack level? For instance, can there ever be a scenario where the records and fields have to outlive `input_buffer`?

Comment: @greatwolf: No, that would be bad :)  It's a batch application, and once one "transmission" has been processed, that's it for the buffer and everything that was extracted from it, and it's on to the next.

Comment: @KarthikT: I've read about move semantics but it's not clear to me how they would help here.  I thought they had more to do with transferring "ownership" of entire strings, whereas I'm trying to instantiate strings whose contents are substrings of a shared string.

Comment: @Chap Sorry I didnt realize there were substrings involved.. serves me right for jumping the gun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this sounds like a good candidate for [boost::string_ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html#string_ref.examples).
You would simply do `boost::string_ref input(input_buffer);`  and then pass `string_ref`s up the stack instead. The only thing you have to worry about is keeping the original buffer alive the whole time.

Comment: From your link: "A string_ref is a read-only reference to a contiguous sequence of characters, and provides much of the functionality of std::string. A string_ref is cheap to create, copy and pass by value, because it does not actually own the storage that it points to.  A string_ref is implemented as a small struct that contains a pointer to the start of the character data and a count."  This sounds very promising, and since I do have access to Boost (hopefully 1.53 or later, when string_ref was introduced) I will look further into it.

Comment: @Chap: If possible, you will want to use latest version of boost. `string_ref` was just introduced in 1.53, so 1.54 and 1.55 have more mature implementations.

Comment: Our boost level is determined by what the CentOS / yum people certify, and we're current only at 1.41.  If it turns out there's no way (within our company policies) to install even a local 1.55, I'm soliciting other ideas.  (At worst, I'll just pass around pointers and counts.)